# wordpress add post validation

Tags: javascript, wordpress, validation

This is embarrassing, but yet i am surprised to see that there is no validation by default while adding a new post in wordpress. When i don't enter a title and even content, and just hit Publish, it says that the post is published, and when i view the front end, there is no new post.

How could wordpress skip the simple validation for adding a post? Atleast i expected a server side validation (if not client side). Don't know why the validation is skipped. It is upto wordpress, whether they incorporate it in the new versions.

But i want to know how can i add a javascript (or jquery) validation for adding a post in wordpress.
I know it must not at all be difficult. But being new to wordpress, i would like to get some hint.

From Firebug, i could see the form is rendering like:

```
<form id="post" method="post" action="post.php" name="post">
...
</form>
```

Where shall i put my javascript validation code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug, `WordPress` intentionally do this (to save revisions AFAIK). anyways, this may work but could be better ways than this (paste in your `functions.php` file)

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'custom_error_notice' );
function custom_error_notice(){
    global $current_screen, $post;
    if ( $current_screen->parent_base == 'edit' ){
        if((!$post->post_name && !$post->post_content) && $_GET['post']) {
            wp_redirect(admin_url('post-new.php?empty=1'));
        }
        if($_GET['empty']) echo '<div class="error"><p>Warning - Please fill up all fields correctly!</p></div>';
    }
}
```

Also, this is required to use `wp_redirect` and to `avoid header already sent error message`, paste this in your `functions.php` at the top of all other code

```
function callback($buffer) {
    // You can modify $buffer here, and then return the updated code
    return $buffer;
}
function buffer_start() { ob_start("callback"); }
function buffer_end() { ob_end_flush(); }

// Add hooks for output buffering
add_action('init', 'buffer_start');
add_action('wp_footer', 'buffer_end');
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, You are right, WordPress don't have validation in Post Edit Screen,

Why don't you try [Post require Fields](https://github.com/interconnectit/required-fields) plugin, Where you can easily **Check** What to validate, You don't require to write single line of code of javascript or PHP.

Here is screenshot for Backend Management

[image]

Comment: I have tried this plugin, but this is validating only for edit post, not for new post.